# Show / hide parent div with class in child div on button action

Tags: jquery, html

I'm struggling about this issue.
I'd like to hide and show parent div holder_block with some class in the child div on button action. This is what a have so far:
html

```
<div class="legenda_btn" id="events_now">active</div>
<div class="legenda_btn" id="events_come">expect</div>

<div class="holder_block">
    <div class="events_now">active</div>
</div>
<div class="holder_block">
    <div class="events_come">expect</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('.legenda_btn').click(function(){
    $('.holder_block').slideUp('slow'); 
    $('.holder_block').find('.'+$(this).attr('id')).filter(':hidden')
.slideDown('slow');
});
```

What's wrong with this?
I think it's a selector, but I can't fix it...
regards,
Thom

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqmrbpkt/1)

```
$('.legenda_btn').click(function () {
    var attri = $(this).attr('id');
    $("." + attri).parent().parent().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: hi, thnxs. but it toggles only the child div

Comment: No it toggles the parent div. Check your console.

Comment: is this because in my example it's in the first child, but in real it's child in a child

Comment: Yeah then you should go two parents up. Edited the fiddle and the code. Good luck!

Comment: ok, it's getting closer! it works, the div toggles, but the other div displays also, i like to show only the active div on active button, the expect div on expect button

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want to obtain, maybe this:

```js
$('.legenda_btn').click(function () {
    var theSel = "."+$(this).attr('id');
    $(".holder_block").find(theSel).slideDown();
    $(".holder_block").find(":not("+theSel+")").slideUp();
});
```

```css
.holder_block {
    border:1px solid black;
        padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="legenda_btn" id="events_now">active</div>
<div class="legenda_btn" id="events_come">expect</div>

<div class="holder_block">
<div class="events_now">active</div>
</div>
<div class="holder_block">
<div class="events_come">expect</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but it doesn't work in my situation. this is what i have so far. it works, but i think there's a cleaner approach. $('.legenda_btn').click(function () {
    var attri = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".holder_block").not("." + attri).slideUp();
    $("." + attri).parent().parent().parent().slideDown();
});